# Top questions and answers != Лучшие вопросы и ответы

Tags: предложение, локализация

Лента вопросов на главной странице сайта озаглавлена "Лучшие вопросы". В оригинале это "Top questions".

Этот заголовок вводит в заблуждение. Представленные вопросы - никак не лучшие. На самом деле они просто последние, в которых была какая-то активность.

Предлагаю везде исправить "Лучшие" на "Последние".

- [Top questions and answers](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40266732?key=ef25c0fb7f469f403e2aa1e76e6d4f40)
- [Top Questions](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40266732?key=52bbeeeb93577004677050859df1afd4)
- [Top questions](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40266732?key=21503c593ebaf689eefb17ec1e161ed7)

Comment: Оно Профиль -> Вопросы -> Голоса не испортит?

Comment: А где используются "Лучшие вопросы и ответы"?

Comment: @Qwertiy точно, одна из этих строк должна быть в профиле. Надо это учесть.

Answer (score 4):

`Лучшие вопросы` (`Top questions`) идут заголовком во вкладках 
[Текущие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/?tab=active), 
[Конкурсные](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured), 
[Горячие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/?tab=hot), 
[Неделя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/?tab=week) и
[Месяц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/?tab=month).
Причём в начало списка попадают за дату вопроса, ответа или редактирования. Т.е., по сути это `Последние вопросы, ответы и обновления`.

Предлагаю перевод

> Последние обновления

Comment: Кстати, хорошо, мне нравится.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, пора делать исправления на transifex?

Comment: Я бы всё же не стал менять "вопросы" на "обновления".

Comment: @alexolut Добавьте аргументы, пожалуйста.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky есть проблема с контекстом (см.отдельный ответ). Ну и в списке всё же именно вопросы, а не обновления. Будь там обновления - следовало бы некий timeline выводить, который включал бы вопросы, ответы, конкурсы и т.п.

Answer (score 2):

Основная сложность здесь в том, что "Top Questions" на главной - это последние активные вопросы. А "Top Questions" в профиле - это лучшие (по кол-ву голосов) вопросы.

В transifex нельзя сделать разный перевод для одинаковых строк. Поэтому либо надо выбрать хорошо подходящий вариант для обоих случаев, либо перевод не трогать, но потрогать разработчиков, участвующих в механизме локализации SO, чтобы каким-то образом была обеспечена возможность перевода именно с учётом контекста.

Правда при этом есть две строки (отличаются регистром второго слова):

- [Top Questions](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40267078?key=52bbeeeb93577004677050859df1afd4)
- [Top questions](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/64898497?key=21503c593ebaf689eefb17ec1e161ed7)

Хорошо бы выяснить, где используется второй вариант.

В качестве общего перевода можно использовать просто "Топ вопросов". См. [Топ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BF) на вики.

Comment: По моему, очевидно, что тексты на главной и в профиле **должны** браться из **разных** источников. В конце-концов рядом в профиле (в секции "ответы") есть же текст *Лучшие ответы*

Comment: @avp кто же спорит-то. Но пока первичный текст добайтово совпадает - обеспечить разные переводы не представляется возможным.

Comment: А спросить разработчиков?

Comment: @avp это к Николаю вопрос. Но я примерно уже знаю ответ :)

Comment: Если из одного места, то это ошибка и ее надо править

Comment: Топ – очень плохо звучит.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky ну, не знаю ... топ-модели не возражают.

Answer (score 2):

По сути это "Текущие вопросы". Давайте так и переведём.

Comment: Не забывайте про контекст. В профиле это уже не "текущие вопросы". Но для главной, кмк, пойдёт, если сможем различить строки.

Answer (score -3):

Вообще убрать эту надпись (можно заменить на пробелы).

Comment: Эээ? За что её так?

Comment: @Qwertiy, лично я вообще ее заметил (на главной странице) только когда прочел этот вопрос. Там и без нее все очевидно.

Comment: Зачем тогда удалять, если Вы её и так не видите? :)