# Текущие текущие вопросы

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

После замены "Лучшие вопросы" на ["Текущие вопросы"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4502/176217) главная страница стала выглядеть несколько странно на мой взгляд:

> [image: текущие]

Речь об одновременном отображении с вкладкой "текущие".

На enSO подобная вкладка называется "interesting":

> [image: interesting]

Но как я понял, её [содержимое всё же отличается](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34704021#34704021) от того, что отображается на ruSO. Т.к. у нас используется более старая версия сайта.

В связи с этим вопрос: надо ли что-то тут изменить в названиях или "текущие текущие" не так страшны?

Comment: А почему выбрали вариант «Текущие вопросы»? Это далеко не самый популярный вариант в голосовании, там лидирует «Последние обновления».

Comment: @NickVolynkin [локализаторский-произвол](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34679078#34679078).

Comment: И в чём его смысл?

Answer (score 1):

А может просто обновимся до новой версии и поменяем название на "интересные"? Если не согласны, то аргументируйте.

Comment: Давайте, обновимся. У Вас адрес git репозитория с кодом SO имеется? :)

Comment: @alexolut Я так полагаю Николас это может сделать, верно?