# Кавычки для метки

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, знаки

Как известно, [знаки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) бывают разных типов. [Некоторые](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=Tags&filter=all) из них привязаны к активности по меткам. В блоке репутации профиля может быть обнаружена такая строка:

> [image: профиль]

Видно, что в данном случае метка по языку ***C*** никак не выделена в тексте (как и в заголовке: *"Бронзовый знак за метку c"*). Мне кажется, её следует обрамить кавычками, чтобы концовка фразы выглядела так:

> вопросы с меткой «c»

В принципе, это легко было бы сделать путём уточнения текущего перевода в transifex:

> [Earn at least $score$ total score for at least $answerScoreStr$ non-community wiki answers in the $tagLink$ tag](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/48712614?key=b7bb617e5c6b35465215b435b61ffb5a)

> Заработать не менее $score$ баллов рейтинга за минимум $answerScoreStr$ ответов, не отмеченных как общие, на вопросы с меткой $tagLink$

Но сложность заключается в том, что эта же строка используется в другом контексте. Например, в [описании упомянутого знака](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/116/c) на странице знаков:

> [image: знаки]

Здесь кавычки будут лишними, так как метка уже выделена в тексте. Т.о. исправление первой ситуации может сломать вторую. Чтобы этого не произошло, первое, что приходит на ум - это разделение контекстов используемых строк. Как показала ситуация с ["Top questions"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3126/176217), такое разделение вполне может быть обеспечено разработчиками. И вроде ответственные работники [должны быть уведомлены](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34784020#34784020).

Дополнительно предлагаю рассмотреть целесообразность добавления кавычек вокруг слова "общие" в упомянутой фразе, чтобы было так:

> ... ответов, не отмеченных как «общие», на вопросы ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если уж нужно что-то кавычкоподобное, то может квадратные скобки?

Поиск по меткам использует квадратные скобки. В заголовках метатем по меткам мы тоже используем квадратные скобки. Так почему же в знаках мы хотим увидеть кавычки, которые будут смотреться не так, как везде?

Comment: Хорошая идея, её наверное даже есть смысл глобально запросить. Нет желания на meta.SE оформить? :)

Comment: @alexolut, что именно запросить? Это же то же самое, что у тебя, но только знаки другие.

Comment: Я начал обсуждение именно применительно к ruSO. Но вариант с квадратными скобками будет актуален для всех сайтов SE.

Comment: Оформил [заявочку](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289866/339911) :)

Answer (score 1):

Для наименования метки более строгий вариант правил русского языка рекомендует (см. либо [грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters?id=75), либо [Мильчин А.Э. "Справочная книга редактора и корректора"](http://www.az-print.com/FAQ/HelpBook/)) использовать кавычки, в которых ставить название метки в именительном падеже.

Я конкретно сошлюсь на пункт, который относится к медалям, орденам: "3.24. Ордена, медали, знаки, знамена, грамоты, премии". Знаки относятся напрямую (например, знак «Фанатик»), пометы и метки с натяжкой, но по аналогии - вполне: метка «entity-framework».

При этом давайте прямо скажем: во многих случаях правила русского языка, которые мы привыкли относить к нормам делового письма можно лишь с некоторыми натяжками использовать в интерфейсах информационных систем, в т.ч. в интернете. Допускаю, что в какой-то момент будут зафиксированы основные принятые способы, а пока многое остаётся на откуп конкретному редактору, фиксируется в стайл гайдах.

В некоторых случаях возможно отступление от правила: если у вас будет длинный список из меток, при этом вы каждую обрамите в кавыки -- это будет правильно, но несколько тяжеловесно. Если у вас основной цвет букв текста - чёрный, а каждая метка является ссылкой и цвет ссылок отличается от основного цвета букв - то вполне можно убрать кавычки.

В качестве примера могу привести информационную систему гугл, которая в какой-то момент приняла решение не подчёркивать ссылки. Это было непривычно, многими дизайнерами воспринималось как нестандартное решение, однако постепенно получает все больше распространение. Вероятно, тоже может стать новым стандартом и будет зафиксировано.

Конкретно в этом месте я думаю, что лучше поставить кавычки. Особенно хорошо будет смотреться в коротких метках, типа "си" и "си++", иначе не сразу и сообразишь.

Напоминаю, что основной вид кавычек в русском языке - [кавычки «ёлочками»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8).

По части необходимости кавычек на слове "общий". Кавычки в русском языке используются в [нескольких случаях](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/53-kav1), в данном случае нет никакой нужды. Здесь нет использования слова "общий" в переносном смысле (и тем более - ироническом смысле ;-) ), это значение давно является общеупотребительным в настоящее время. Впрочем, если вы считаете, что данный термин является неизвестным, либо малоупотребимым ;-) на нашем сайте -- то также необходимо взять в кавычки.

Answer (score 0):

А может лучше ссылку на метку поставить, как во втором варианте?

Comment: И в заголовке тоже?

Comment: @alexolut, ой.. Хотя можно как-то выделить.

Comment: Вот об этом и речь. Выделить как-то обязательно надо. Кавычки - лишь один из вариантов.

Comment: @alexolut, тоже ссылку, но классическую, а не прямоугольную меткообразную.