# Перевести e.g. в метках

Tags: дефект, локализация, метки

Сейчас при написании вопроса на основном сайте показывается такой плейсхолдер:

> [image: скриншот]

Надо бы заменить это "e.g." на "например," и убрать скобки.

Answer (score 1):

Я сделал перевод с квадратными скобками с учётом Вашего же [ответа](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4560/176217) по смежной проблеме:

> например, [список меток]

Жалко, что каждую метку нельзя обрамить отдельно, но так уж строка приходит из англоязычного движка.

Я на MSE оставлял заявку на необходимость подобного разделения меток в списке: [Forbidden tags popup isn’t consistent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308396/339911), но что-то мнения разделились +3/-3 на вопросе сейчас.

Обновления будут на сайте, когда сотрудник SO сочтёт это необходимым.

Comment: Но в этом поле метки пишутся без скобок. Предлагаю вообще никакими знаками не обрамлять.

Comment: @Qwertiy тогда надо сделать всё же круглые как на Мете сейчас. Или убрать везде вообще скобки. Короче говоря, хорошо бы единобразия добиться. А вообще, предлагаю посмотреть как оно будет с квадратными и принять решение чуть позже. Всё же квадратные скобки можно вводить в поле меток, в этом плане они совершенно не мешают, как и круглые.

Comment: Но это же просто пример. На мой взгляд там скобки не нужны.