# Почему на SOru на странице описания метки оная в заголовке заключена в [], а на SOen в ''?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, локализация, метки

В заголовке на [странице описании метка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) у нас метка заключена в `[]`:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А на [странице описания метки на SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) в `''`:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему у нас метка в заголовке заключена в `[]`, а на SOen `''`?

Comment: потому что у нас она заключена в `[]` а у них в `''` :)

Comment: самое важная деталь)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR; **Это «локализаторский произвол».**

---

Был ранее вопрос на Мете: [Кавычки для метки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4546/176217) по результатам которого было решено, использовать квадратные скобки для выделения метки везде, где это разумно. Даже предложен фича-реквест сделать это глобально на всех сайтах: 
[Add square brackets around tag name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289866/339911)